# are there differences in browser loading speeds for different Images extension (jpg, png)?

Tags: css, optimization, browser

I have an image that I want to convert to png / jpg.
The file size differences for each type is very small (photoshop save-for-web-and-devices optimized):
155 bytes for image.png
357 bytes for image.jpg

I don't care too much about the file type either, because there is no opacity.

Is there any difference in loading speeds for browsers between images types?
say, for example, firefox prefers .png files because they're uncompressed so it loads faster (just a thought).

thanks

Comment: The file-type has not much to do with the loading speed. How fast a browser loads depends on factors like file size, file amount, max parallel connections, overhead and so on.

Comment: It's obvious that the file size plays an important role.
I was referring to the image type.

I'll rephrase:
Assuming I have 2 files: image.png & image.jpg, both are 1M size. Both take exactly the same time to download. Does the time that it takes for a browser to render each of the images is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading speed of an image depends on the size of the file and the connection speed of the user.  When a site is loaded, a browser downloads a temporary copy of the page including images.  You may not be able to tell the difference, but the JPG will take twice as long to load at 355 bytes.  These files are so small that it really should not make a difference in the loading speed unless you had say 100 unique images on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to test a very large sample to find the difference between rendering two different file types. Even with such a small size difference, the smaller file size would probably give you a greater difference than the file type.

The only way to know for sure would be to try it and measure it - then repeat a load of times to get a good sample of data.

If you are really looking to ultra-optimise, reducing the number of requests would give you more benefit than either the file size (based on the numbers you supplied) or the file type - so you could opt for image-sprites to reduce `n` images to 1 image.